# It's a good idea in spacy use set_extension into new component function?

Tags: spacy

I'm following the Spacy NLP course. In the [chapter 3](https://course.spacy.io/en/chapter3/#12) section 12, there is an example for adding a new component to a blank pipeline and, also they add an attribute extension with the set_extension function, but they add the attribute OUT OF the component function.

It,s not a good idea set a new extension in a new component function?
I've tested the idea:

```py
import json
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.tokens import Span
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

with open("countries.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    COUNTRIES = json.loads(f.read())

with open("capitals.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    CAPITALS = json.loads(f.read())

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("COUNTRY", list(nlp.pipe(COUNTRIES)))


def is_country(span):
    return span.label_=="COUNTRY"

@Language.component("countries_component")
def countries_component(doc):
    #Add de attribute extension
    Span.set_extension("capital",default=None, validate = "is_country", force = True)
    #Creates an span wit "COUNTRY" label for all matches
    matches = matcher(doc)
    ents = []
    for id, start, end in matches:
      #Marc the span with the label COUNTRY
      span_country = Span(doc, start, end, label="COUNTRY")
      #Save the capital in the new attribute
      span_country._.capital = CAPITALS.get(span_country.text)
      ents.append(span_country)

    doc.ents = tuple(ents)
    return doc

# Adding component to pipeline
nlp.add_pipe("countries_component")
print(nlp.pipe_names)
```

In my version, i'm setting the attribute extension in the component. But without the force  = true, the component generates an error when creating a new second and later doc because it detects there already is an ._.capital atribute seted. It's solved setting the force = True argument. But it has made me doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to do this.

Instead of `force=True`, another option is to check if it's already been set and skip otherwise:

```py
if not Span.has_extension("capital"):
    Span.set_extension(...)
```

In contrast to `force=True`, you don't know for sure whether `"capital"` is your version with your defaults+validation, since it could technically have been set by another user component/library, but in most applications this isn't a concern and it could be a bit faster.